# Why is there a for in a sentence?

Tags: python-2.7

In python, I meet a situation where there is a for in a list. I don't know what's the meaning of that.

```html
scores = [game.state.getScore() for game in games]
```

---

I meet it in the project called pacman, which is a project in a AI(Artificial Intelligence).
It is on the 550-580 lines in the pacman.py .

Comment: [Did you even look?](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction is called a `list comprehension` in python. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more details.

In brief, this is another way of writing the code below:

```
scores = []
for game in games:
    score.append(game.state.getScore())
```